# loop through API JSON data and count status'

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am getting data from a rest API with the requests library on a function:

```
def read_compressors():

    x = requests.get('http://10.200.200.223:5000/bacnet/read/multiple',json=my_rtu_read)
    print(x.status_code)
    return x.json()
```

Where x looks like this:

```
{'status': 'read_success', 'data': {'cooling_stage_1': {'pv': 'active'}, 'cooling_stage_2': {'pv': 'active'}, 'cooling_stage_3': {'pv': 'inactive'}, 'cooling_stage_4': {'pv': 'inactive'}}}
```

How do I loop through the `data` and count all of the cooling stages that are `active`? In `data` there could be many stages but in this example there is only 4, `cooling_stage_1` through `cooling_stage_4`. Hopefully this makes sense!

If I call the function and attempt to loop through it:

```
x = read_compressors()
print("x is:",x)

temporary_counter = 0 #use this to count += active???
for status,data in x.items():
    print(data)
    
    for k,v in data.items():
        print(k,v)
```

This errors out:

```
200
x is: {'status': 'read_success', 'data': {'cooling_stage_1': {'pv': 'inactive'}, 'cooling_stage_2': {'pv': 'inactive'}, 'cooling_stage_3': {'pv': 'inactive'}, 'cooling_stage_4': {'pv': 'inactive'}}}
read_success
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\rtuTest.py", line 47, in <module>
    for k,v in data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
>>>
```

Any tips appreciated...

Comment: Bad api design. Numbered keys should be lists so they can be indexed and iterated over.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that more? What should the API response look like?

Comment: @MarkTolonen would you have any links so I can read up / learn what your mentioning? Thank you!

Comment: It could be `{"cooling_stage":["active", "active", "inactive", "inactive"]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'status': 'read_success',
     'data': {'cooling_stage_1': {'pv': 'active'},
              'cooling_stage_2': {'pv': 'active'},
              'cooling_stage_3': {'pv': 'inactive'},
              'cooling_stage_4': {'pv': 'inactive'}
              }
     }




temporary_counter = 0


for stuff in x['data'].values():    
    for clg_cmd in stuff.values():
        if clg_cmd == 'active':
            temporary_counter += 1

print(temporary_counter)
```